# After Sharing a FB-link, insert into mysql not working

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, facebook

Hey I have a problem...

I would like to when a user has shared a link from my facebook app, that i get his id into my db.

The way i share the link is via the facebook dialog javascript example that i have modified

**The sharing javascript code**

```
<script>
      FB.init({appId: 'xxxx', channelUrl: 'xxxx', status: true, cookie: true});

      function postToFeed() {

        // calling the API ...
        var obj = {
          method: 'feed',
          link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
          picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
          name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
          caption: 'Reference Documentation',
          description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
        };

        function callback(response) {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
                    document.getElementById('post').style.display = "none";
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("POST","shared.php",true);
            xmlhttp.send("id=xxx");
        }

        FB.ui(obj, callback);
      }

</script>
```

The PHP Code

```
$con = mysqli_connect("xxxx","xxx","xxx","xxx");
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    };

        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO xxx (fb-id) VALUES (".$_POST['id'].")");

    mysqli_close($con)
```

When I have shared the link I get the post_id, but the nothing in the db ?

Can anybody tell whats wrong ?

Comment: You might want to confirm that Facebook's policies allow you to store that user's ID.

Comment: I'm allow too store userIDs, but not their usernames and password ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Invalid field name:

```
INSERT INTO xxx (fb-id) ...
                 ^^^^^
```

That looks like two fields being subtracted, not a single field. You'll probably want to escape it with backticks to force seeing it as a single field name:

```
INSERT INTO xxx (`fb-id`) ...
```

In the greature picture, you've got a major gaping [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com). Stop working on this code and learn about how to avoid this problem before someone destroys your server.

You're also assuming the query succeeded, which is a bad thing to do. You've got error handling on the connect() call, but nowhere else. NEVER EVER assume a query has succeeded. Always check for errors afterwards.

Comment: I know theres a major gap in my sql code, but i'll fix that when i can the code to insert into the database, i just have stripped the code down to a minimum ;)